# MergeSort in Rust

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, rust

I've just started learning Rust and put together this working MergeSort implementation. Wondering what I've overlooked and what I could improve.

I couldn't figure out a cleaner way to deal with the `Option` type returned by the iterator than just checking that values weren't `None` and then `.unwrap()`ing my results but I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Included working test cases. Let me know if there's a case I missed.

```
pub fn merge_sort(mut input: Vec<usize>) -> Vec<usize> {
    let length = input.len();
    // Base case
    if length < 2 {
        return input;
    }

    let right = merge_sort(input.split_off(length / 2));
    let left = merge_sort(input);

    let mut left_iter = left.iter().peekable();
    let mut right_iter = right.iter().peekable();

    let mut merged = Vec::new();
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < length {
        if left_iter.peek() > right_iter.peek() && right_iter.peek() != None {
            merged.push(*(right_iter.next().unwrap()));
        } else if left_iter.peek() != None {
            merged.push(*(left_iter.next().unwrap()));
        }
        i += 1;
    }

    merged
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use merge_sort;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(merge_sort(vec![4, 3]), vec![3, 4]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_base_case() {
        assert_eq!(merge_sort(vec![3]), vec![3]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn totally_backwards() {
        assert_eq!(
            merge_sort(vec![100, 90, 50, 14, 9, 7, 3]),
            vec![3, 7, 9, 14, 50, 90, 100]
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) (Do you know [rustdoc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rustdoc/what-is-rustdoc.html)? (Note the `beta`.))

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for that, I didn't know rustdoc until you mentioned it. (Also learning ...)

Comment: ([Non-beta rustdoc book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/what-is-rustdoc.html).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** I'm also new to Rust, but I have a background in C, C++ and Haskell. Take everything I say with a grain of salt.</sup>

All of that looks reasonable, except for the `while` loop and the ownership. And there's a bug.

## Bug on sorted vectors

Did you try your code on sorted sets?

```
#[test]
fn it_works_on_sorted() {
    assert_eq!(merge_sort(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]), vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
}
```

Your code won't work. Instead, you'll end up with `vec![1]`. That's because

```
left_iter.peek() > right_iter.peek()
```

is `false` as soon as we run out of elements on the left hand side, since

```
None < Some(x)
```

is always true for all `x`. But in this case we won't add the elements from the right hand side! Instead, we look at our now empty left list:

```
if left_iter.peek() != None {
    // left_iter.peek() is None, not executed
    merged.push(*(left_iter.next().unwrap()));
}
// ALWAYS executed
i += 1;
```

Since `i += 1` is always executed, we end up with `i == length`, although we never actually `push`ed the right-hand side. So `i < length` hides a bug. The next section shows how to get rid of that one:

## While

Why do we have to keep track of the length of our vector? We have iterators at hand, so that shouldn't be necessary, right? When either of our iterators is at end, we fill our vector with the rest.

That's rather easy:

```
while let (Some(&x), Some(&y)) = (left_iter.peek(), right_iter.peek()) {
    if *x <= *y {
        merged.push(*(left_iter.next().unwrap()))
    } else {
        merged.push(*(right_iter.next().unwrap()))
    }
}

for x in left_iter {
    merged.push(*x)
}

for y in right_iter {
    merged.push(*y)
}
```

## `Vector::new()` vs `Vector::with_capacity`

We already know that `merged` will have `length` elements, therefore we should use [`Vector::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) instead:

```
let mut merged = Vec::with_capacity(length);
```

## Ownership

`merge_sort` could take a slice instead of a vector. That way it's more general. The actual implementation is left as an exercise, but it's more or less the same:

````
/// Sorts a slice in-place with mergesort.
///
/// ```
/// let mut example = [1,4,2,5,3];
///
/// merge_sort_inplace(example)
/// assert_eq!(example, [1,2,3,4,5]);
/// ```
pub fn merge_sort_inplace(input: &mut [usize]) {
    let length = input.len();

    if length < 2 {
        return;
    }

    let (left, right) = input.split_at_mut(length / 2);

    merge_sort_inplace(left);
    merge_sort_inplace(right);

    // ... similar to your variant
}
````

Note that the name is slightly a misnomer, `merge_sort_inplace` will still need \$\mathcal \Theta(n)\$ additional memory [unless you pull some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm).

We can even re-use that variant if you still want to take ownership of the vector:

```
fn merge_sort(mut input: Vec<usize>) -> Vec<usize> {
    merge_sort_inplace(&mut input);
    input
}
```

Comment: Since it's not obvious from your sample code, I should note that your  `merge_sort_inplace` will still need to allocate a temporary array to store the merge results (or, alternatively, to copy the halves of the input before sorting them, and then merge them back into the original array). [There are ways around that, sort of,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm) but they're not simple and they still require *some* extra work space for temporary results.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I've added a remark, but I didn't mean `merge_sort_inplace` to be completely in-place, just the result to get written back into the `&mut input`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was able to get a [final implementation with slices](https://gist.github.com/cbzehner/e3f899f85a78117ee54f72a47ab28ccd). 

The most interesting thing I had to solve here was creating the `merged` Vec outside a new scope so that the borrowing of ownership used when creating `left` and `right` would expire. Not an original idea, I borrowed it from [this implementation](https://github.com/nbigaouette/rust-sorting/blob/master/src/efficientsorts/merge.rs)

Comment: @ChristopherZehner good job. I would put the initialization of `merged` after sorting both sides, though, e.g. just write `let mut merged;` and later write `merged = Vec::with_capacity(length);` after you sorted the left and right side. That way, you will use at most one copy of your array, whereas allocation `merged` before you sort the subranges leads to (almost) two copies.

Answer (score 4):

The one obvious thing I see is that you are consuming the input. I'd suggest you try using [slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/)  instead, so that you don't consume the inputs and you don't have to spend time and memory splitting the vector.

Comment: Consuming the input might still be necessary when extending this vector to support types that are not `Copy`, e.g. sorting a `Vec<String>`. I need to consume the input so that the elements can be moved to the output Vec. I don't think even a `&mut [T]` mutable slice would be sufficient? Of course, this is irrelevant for a `Vec<usize>` where operating on slices would be much more elegant.