# Rust Iterative and Recursive Merge Sort Implementation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rust, mergesort

I'm in the process of learning both Rust and algorithms after primarily focusing on web development. As such I've had a go at implementing merge sort both iteratively and recursively.

I've looked for various implementations in Rust online and found them either to be quite complex, quite specific (for types/use-cases) or quite hard to reason the flow of logic through - although [MergeSort in Rust](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189330/mergesort-in-rust) and the comment by *Zeta* proved to be very useful!

Both implementations appear to be passing all the test cases, however if anyone is able to provide me with any feedback/pointers on how to improve/optimise the algorithms (or any missed test scenarios) it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm particularly interested in ensuring both would have `O(nlog(n))` time complexity - which I think the recursive one would, but I'm not so sure about the iterative one?

#### Recursive Merge Sort

```rust
pub fn recursive_merge_sort<T>(collection: &mut [T])
where
    T: Ord + Copy,
{
    if collection.len() > 1 {
        let (lhs, rhs) = collection.split_at_mut(collection.len() / 2);
        recursive_merge_sort(lhs);
        recursive_merge_sort(rhs);
        merge(collection, collection.len())
    }
}
```

#### Iterative Merge Sort

```rust
pub fn iterative_merge_sort<T>(collection: &mut [T])
where
    T: Ord + Copy,
{
    let length = collection.len();
    if length <= 1 {
        return;
    }

    let mut current_sub_array_multiplier = 1;
    let mut current_sub_array_size = 2;

    loop {
        collection
            .chunks_mut(current_sub_array_size)
            .for_each(|sub_arr| merge(sub_arr, current_sub_array_size));

        if current_sub_array_size > length {
            break;
        }

        current_sub_array_multiplier += 1;
        current_sub_array_size = 2f64.powi(current_sub_array_multiplier) as usize;
    }
}
```

#### Merge Function

```rust
pub fn merge<T>(collection: &mut [T], sub_array_length: usize)
where
    T: Ord + Copy,
{
    if sub_array_length < 2 {
        return;
    }

    let mut temp_vec = Vec::with_capacity(collection.len());
    {
        let mid = sub_array_length / 2;
        let mut lhs = collection.iter().take(mid).peekable();
        let mut rhs = collection.iter().skip(mid).peekable();

        while let (Some(&lhs_el), Some(&rhs_el)) = (lhs.peek(), rhs.peek()) {
            if *lhs_el <= *rhs_el {
                temp_vec.push(*lhs.next().unwrap())
            } else {
                temp_vec.push(*rhs.next().unwrap())
            }
        }

        for el in lhs {
            temp_vec.push(*el);
        }

        for el in rhs {
            temp_vec.push(*el);
        }
    }

    assert_eq!(temp_vec.len(), collection.len());
    temp_vec
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(i, el)| collection[i] = *el);
}
```

*Sample Test cases:*

````rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod recursive_tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_semi_sorted() {
        let mut arr = vec![1, 23, 2, 32, 29, 33];
        recursive_merge_sort(&mut arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, [1, 2, 23, 29, 32, 33]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_backwards() {
        let mut arr = vec![50, 25, 10, 5, 1];
        recursive_merge_sort(&mut arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_sorted() {
        let mut arr = vec![1, 5, 10, 25, 50];
        recursive_merge_sort(&mut arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, [1, 5, 10, 25, 50]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_empty() {
        let mut arr: Vec<u32> = vec![];
        recursive_merge_sort(&mut arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, []);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_len_two() {
        let mut arr = vec![5, 1];
        recursive_merge_sort(&mut arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, [1, 5]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_partially_sorted() {
        let mut arr = vec![50, 75, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 50];
        recursive_merge_sort(&mut arr);
        assert_eq!(arr, [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 50, 50, 75]);
    }
}

```
````